# Organising data with ADODC (VB6)

Tags: datagrid, vb6, ado, recordset

I am creating a program for my school project and one of the tasks are to put the information that is in the DataGrid in alphabetical order and in order by there number (ID). i am using `Adodc1.Recordset` but I cannot figure out how to order the information. I have created the program to add, edit and delete the records but i do not know how to organise the records in alphabetical order and by their ID.
Thanks to anyone that could help. :)

Comment: Please can you show the code you have for loading the RecordSet.  It may be a s simple as using the Sort method but without seeing more of your code it is hard to be sure.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder This is the code that i am using:

Comment: `connSearch.Open connstr`
    `Adodc1.ConnectionString = Conn.connstr`
    `Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1`
    `Adodc1.Visible = False`

Comment: OK, the Sort property should help.  Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681750(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok sweet, thanks a lot for your response and time @OldBoyCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a while. I did not need the connection and all i needed was a simple piece of code.

```
Private Sub cmdSort_Click()
    Adodc1.Recordset.Sort = "LastName"   'data field name
End Sub
```